# Stack cv2 Frame of RGB channel and Single Channel together

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

What I am looking to do is make it so that I can stack the 4 Video feeds together, RGB, B, G, R Channels in a quad frame feed.  Here is my code I get the error "All the input arrays must have same number of dimensions.  I wanted to know if there is a way to work through or around this?  If you insert GRAY where RGB is you can see the overall result I am wanting other than the RGB Frame should be where the GRAY Frame is.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
ret, frame = cap.read()

while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    # Resizing down the image to fit in the screen.
    b,g,r = cv2.split(frame)
    RGB = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA)
    GRAY = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # creating another frame.
    channels = cv2.split(frame)
    frame_merge = cv2.merge(channels)

    # horizintally concatenating the two frames.
    final_frame = cv2.hconcat((frame, frame_merge))
    final_frame2 = cv2.hconcat((frame, frame_merge))
    final = cv2.vconcat((final_frame, final_frame2))

    frame1 = np.hstack((RGB,b))
    frame2 = np.hstack((g,r))
    final = np.vstack((frame1,frame2))
    cv2.imshow('frame', final)

    k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
    if k == 27:
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my solution:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
ret, frame = cap.read()

red = np.zeros(frame.shape, 'uint8')
green = np.zeros(frame.shape, 'uint8')
blue = np.zeros(frame.shape, 'uint8')

while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    b, g, r = cv2.split(frame)

    red[..., 0], red[..., 1], red[..., 2] = r, r, r
    green[..., 0], green[..., 1], green[..., 2] = g, g, g
    blue[..., 0], blue[..., 1], blue[..., 2] = b, b, b

    final = cv2.vconcat((
        cv2.hconcat((frame, blue)),
        cv2.hconcat((green, red))
    ))

    cv2.imshow('frame', final)

    k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
    if k == 27:
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: If you take my above code and replace the RGB with GRAY after adding GRAY = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) you can see the results I am kind of going for.  If you hold a red object in front of the camera you can see the red channel accentuate the red and so on for the other colors.  Mainly just instead of the first GRAY Frame I want it to be the regular colored Frame.

Comment: @MichaelHenderson Not sure if i understood correctly, that means my solution wasn't what you were trying to achieve before editing?

Comment: @MichaelHenderson I've added a new solution, please let me know if that's what you're looking for, otherwise please explain a little bit more.